# Custom Deque reference class

Tags: java

Does anyone know where i can find a deque class that is different than the one in the API. By that i mean one that can add infront and last and can remove from infront and from last. It should be using a linkedList with a reference to the first and rear.

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't clear.  The [standard Java `Deque` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) offers `addFirst()`, `addLast()`, `removeFirst()`, `removeLast()`, etc.  What is the problem with it?

Comment: What i need is making these methods like pretending it was never in the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [JavaDoc for `Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html), add/remove first and last are already supported. In fact, `LinkedList` already implements `Deque`.

Comment: I need one done from scratch by myself. Basically doing what the API has.